# Scraping Transfermarkt.de with Python (pandas, bs4) - avoid 403

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, http-status-code-403

everyone,

I'd like to review the injury history of all the players. For this purpose I have built a Python Scraper.

I have a function where I can specify player_id_start and player_id_end and then the scraper starts. The scraper works partly with pandas and partly with BeautifulSoup.

After about 10 players, I receive status_code 403 from Transfermarkt.de. I assume that some defense system is blocking my requests. About 5 minutes later, I am "unlocked" again.

Do I forget anything or do I simply have to install some sleep timers? I don't want to slam the server either.

Do I have to pay attention to anything with the header or requests in general? Currently the following is used

```
requests.get(url, headers=heads)

heads = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36'}
```

I'm sure you guys have a few more places I can start. After all, there are 600,000 player IDs.

Thank you

Comment: you can try to use time.sleep(1) or some thing like that. Or look at using proxies..

Answer (score 0):

You have few options, sometimes constructing proper header is a hassle, but it could be done by examining dev tools in a browser - nice [video](https://egghead.io/lessons/chrome-devtools-analyze-http-requests-and-responses-with-chrome-devtools) how to work with chrome dev tools or another [one](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network).

If I will be in your case I will also try first [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) ( or node [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) with plugin [puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth) or golang [chromedp](https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp)), it could leads that you will be not blocked ( or you will be blocked after much more requests than 10) but scraping will be slower. But if those tools will work without problems there is high probability that constructing proper header should solve your problems.

Another relatively cheap options is to modify and extend your scraping function and deploy it on [aws lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) or [google cloud functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/) - for both you have some free quotas per month. You can generate solid amount of those functions in cloud and instead of calling directly the website, you will call function in the cloud, the function will call the website and resend the response to you and when you will get response status code 403, you will use another function. This solution is good if you will **scrape** those data more than once. It is very similar to using proxies.